# Android google maps : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, nullpointerexception

god damn google maps ... : (There are two days that I can not run my app with these blessed maps. I followed countless guides, but nothing, do not want it to work.

I had to manually import the mapFragment because eclipse did not recognize him and so I did the import and now when I run the program I always get:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {.....}

here is the error in full:

```
01-14 14:15:42.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3957): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 14:15:42.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3957): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.IannacconeTedeschi.easyfg/com.IannacconeTedeschi.easyfg.NavigatoreMenu}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 14:15:42.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
01-14 14:15:42.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-14 14:15:42.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-14 14:15:42.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3957):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-14 14:15:42.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3957):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 14:15:42.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3957):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-14 14:15:42.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-14 14:15:42.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3957):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 14:15:42.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3957):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-14 14:15:42.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3957):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-14 14:15:42.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3957):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-14 14:15:42.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3957):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-14 14:15:42.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3957): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 14:15:42.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3957):     at com.IannacconeTedeschi.easyfg.NavigatoreMenu.onCreate(NavigatoreMenu.java:25)
01-14 14:15:42.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3957):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
01-14 14:15:42.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3957):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-14 14:15:42.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
```

### Help Me Please :( :( :(

On the line 25 of NavigatoreMenu.java i have this code:

googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.mapStandard)).getMap();

Help Me Please :(:(:(:(:(:(:(

Comment: post `NavigatoreMenu.java` and indicate line 25.

Comment: You get a `NullPointerException` in `NvigatoreMenu.java` at line 25.

Comment: post your xml file also.

Comment: Did you fix your problem ?
Can you share the solution?

Comment: I had the same problem. My problem is that I replace my API key both in     android:name and in    android:value inside the manifest